# Not able to insert the data inside db

Tags: php

I need help i tried everything but nothing works don't know what's the issue. i want as i check then insert if uncheck then delete but my code doesn't insert

```
       if($this->input->post()){

$select_assigned_ids = $this->input->post('assigned_ids[]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        foreach($select_assigned_ids as $tlusers){
            $data = array(
                        'user_id' => $tlusers
                    );
            $test = $this->assign_permission_model->insert($data);


            } 

}
}else{
    //Checkbox is unchecked....
  $q = 'Delete from assign_permission ';
   $this->section_permission_model->qwr($q); 
}
```

It doesn't insert any value in db

Comment: Can you edit your question with punctuation? It is hard to read and understand right now.

Comment: For performance reasons, you shouldn't be inserting those values one-by-one, but rather in a batch.

Comment: please see my edited question it always deletes data when i refresh page how to prevent this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this code your define array $data remove (,) so insert data

```
    if($this->input->post()){
    $select_assigned_ids = $this->input->post('assigned_ids[]');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            foreach($select_assigned_ids as $tlusers){
                $data = array(
                            'user_id' => $tlusers
                        );
                $test = $this->assign_permission_model->insert($data);

                } 

    }
    }else{
        //Checkbox is unchecked....
      $q = 'Delete from assign_permission ';
      $this->section_permission_model->qwr($q); 
    }
```

Comment: please tell me where i kept flashdata and redirect code so that its gonna redirect on same page

Comment: my else condition always delete data as i refresh page :(

Answer (score 1):

Insert some line code insert data flash maessge

```
if($this->input->post()){
$select_assigned_ids = $this->input->post('assigned_ids[]');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        foreach($select_assigned_ids as $tlusers){
            $data = array(
                        'user_id' => $tlusers
                    );
            $test = $this->assign_permission_model->insert($data);

            } 
         $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div id="message"  class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert" onclick="self.close()">x</a>Success Messages </div>');
                    redirect('redirect your page link'); 
}
}else{
    //Checkbox is unchecked....
  $q = 'Delete from assign_permission ';
  $this->section_permission_model->qwr($q); 
}
```

Comment: my function name is create_evaluation when I use 
redirect('admin/Evaluation/create_evaluation');
then not inserting only display message but
as i used 
redirect('admin/Evaluation/evaluation_form');
worked fine but on refreshing page delete's all record from database

Comment: So you else condition is set eles if not working without action no delete data. which time you delete data query run .

Comment: Want to set required condition if  assigned_ids are  empty how this can be done in this function please help!